# Need to download iMovie '09 on MacBook Pro 16" with iMovie 10

Tags: video, imovie, import, video-editing, firewire

I would like to transfer old Hi8 tapes onto my new MacBook using FireWire.  I have an old Digital Sony Handycam and all of the required adapters to connect it to my MacBook USB-C ports.  I tried importing a tape into iMovie 10 and while it did actually import the portion of the tape I played, the import screen on iMovie 10 had message "No Data Device Detected" the entire time and the audio could have been better. After doing some research it appears that maybe iMovie 10 is not 100% compatible with these old cameras but that iMovie '09 should still be.

So, I would like to download iMovie '09 onto my MacBook in addition to iMovie '10 that I already have.  In other words, I would like to have 2 different versions of iMovie on my MacBook so I can use the '09 version to import old Hi8 tapes and the '10 version for anything in the future.

Is this possible?  I did try to download '09 off the Apple site but after downloading it told me that I had downloaded an update and I already had the newer version so that bright idea didn't work.  I am not a coder so if there is a way to do this without making changes in Terminal mode that would be my preference.

TIA!

Comment: Which Apple site to you download from? Do you want iMovie version 8.0 which is part of iLife \`09 or iMove version 9.0 which is part of iLife \`11?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [tutorial](https://www.movieforwindows.com/imovie/download-imovie-9-0-9.html) on how to extract the older iMovie 09 onto the same Mac as v10 & have both capable of running (I doubt it will work on Catalina or later, but I haven't tested)

---

- Download the iMovie 9.0.9 package… https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1574?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
- Create a folder on your Desktop called iMovie.
- Open the imovie9.0.9update.dmg file to show imovie9.0.9update.pkg
- Drag this .pkg to the folder.
- In Terminal, type `pkgutil --expand` followed by a space, drag iMovie9.0.9Update.pkg to the Terminal window, and then drag the desktop iMovie folder to the Terminal window. Hit Backspace to remove the space, and then type `iMovie` so the full command is

  ```
  pkgutil --expand /Volumes/iMovie\ 9.0.9/iMovie9.0.9Update.pkg Users/[username]/Desktop/iMovie/iMovie
  ```

  Hit Enter, and wait for the extraction to complete. Then quit Terminal.

So we have a new iMovie9.0.9Update.pkg file in the /Desktop/iMovie/iMovie/ folder.

- Right click on it and select Show Package Content.
- In the resulting folder, right click Payload and choose Get Info.
- In the info panel, go to Name & Extension field to add .zip extension.
- Hit Enter and there will be a prompt. Click Add and we get Payload.zip.
- Double click on Payload.zip which will generate a folder Payload 2.
- Go into the Payload 2 folder, next Applications folder and Voila, the iMovie app is there!

Right click the iMovie and select Copy iMovie. Now open Finder and go to the Applications folder, right click on empty space and select Paste Item. Click Keep Both when prompts. To distinguish with the newer iMovie, it's better to rename it to iMovie 9.

Comment: The steps work, but iMovie 9 won't run on Catalina or later (it's at least partially a 32bit application). Been there, done that, and kept a Mini with Mojave exactly for this :-)

Comment: Are you referring to iMovie version 9 or iMovie \`09? Based on the answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301762/is-it-possible-to-download-acquire-imovie-10-1-6), I installed iMovie version 9.0.9 in an El Capitan virtual machine and `About iMovie` returns [this popup](https://imgur.com/a/UifFOSq). This matches the [Wikipedia post about iLife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILife#Releases_and_history). Apparently, there is no iLife \`10 and therefore no iMovie \`10, which the OP refers to.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - Strictly speaking, iMovie '09 is v8.0. v9 is iMovie '11. After that they stopped using the year & just went to iMovie 10.0. v10.0 is from 2013 & has incremented to 10.2.2 for Catalina & later.

Comment: OK. The OP wants iMovie \`09 which is version 8.0. I followed the instructions in your answer and installed iMovie \`11 which is version 9.0.9. There is a download for iMovie [iMovie \`09 version 8.0.6](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL859?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), but at 35.84 MB, I doubt this contains the entire application. Anyway, the answer is to buy a used iLife `09 and install in another (real or virtual) macOS. [Here is one on eBay.](https://www.ebay.com/p/128237345?iid=184407725923)